# Vim search with ag the word under cursor

Tags: vim

I would like to map `<Leader>a` to search with `ag` the word under the cursor

I wrote this:

```
noremap <Leader>a  :Ag!<C-u><C-r>=Escape(expand('<cword>'))<CR>

function! Escape(stuff)
    return substitute(escape(a:stuff, '\/.*$^~[]'), "\n", '\\n', "g")
endfunction
```

Unfortunately when I hit `<Leader>a` on the word `foo` I get this:

```
:foo
```

The `Ag!` vanished and the trailing `<CR>` was not executed.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you added `<c-u>` in your mapping, it will remove `:Ag!`

You may want to use `-Q` for `ag` to do a literal search.

For the `<CR>` problem, your `<CR>` is for the `<c-r>=` expression, you need one extra `<CR>` to launch the command.

Comment: Good, thanks. Then I will use `noremap <leader>a  :Ag! -Q <C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR>`. Why does the `<CR>` is not taken in account?

Comment: Thanks! for me this worked: `noremap <leader>a  :Ag! <C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>` (I removed the `-Q` because it didn't result in what I wnated)

Answer (score 3):

```
noremap <leader>a :Ag! "<cword>"<cr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add answer I found in GitHub answered by [junegunn](https://github.com/junegunn) in case someone needs it

```
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>ag :Ag <C-R><C-W><CR>
```

[Original link](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/issues/50#issuecomment-161676378)